# Getting a date into the database with php from a datepicker

Tags: php, mysql, date, input, datepicker

I have a database field called "dateAdvance" with the type of "date".

```
`dateAdvance` date NOT NULL,
```

In my html I have an input field that has a datepicker jquery attached, so when the user presses the input field  a datepicker appears where you can select a date. The date is going to be in the input field and it is the date that have to be stored in the database.

```
<dl>
     <dt><label for="advancePayment">Acontobetaling:</label></dt>
     <dd><input type="text" name="advancePayment"/></dd>
     <dd><input type="text" name="dateAdvance" class="datepicker"placeholder="Vælge dato"></dd>
</dl>
```

I'm using php to save the data:

```
$dateAdvance=$_POST['dateAdvance']; 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO creatUser(dateAdvance)
    VALUES('$dateAdvance')");
```

Hope there are some who can help me.

Comment: You can cut out 99% of your question with 1 minute of debugging. Print your query before executing it. use mysql_error(). Get rid of all the front-end stuff after confirming its doing its job and sending a date to php. i.e. $dateAdvance has something. Trash all this and start over with a modern database api and read about security. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Top_5#P3:_SQL_Injection

Comment: Uff, that' a messy code... Long live the SQL injection!!!

Comment: I know it is, I am just trying to learn, and have nobody to teach me. So bear with me, somewhere must be the start.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use of deprecated `mysql_*` functions.
2. Really high level of SQL injection (no input data escaping)

Though You didn't tell us which type of datepicker You are using nor which date format did You set for displaying, here is the example how to get the date format for storing into mySQL DB for `date` column:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dateAdvance']));
```

Now, please, google and read a little about PHP PDO or PHP `mysqli_*` functions. I'd go for PDO with (real) prepared statements.

**EDIT:** You have an error in Your PHP code:

```
$dateAdvance=$_POST['total'];
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dateAdvance']));
```

should be

```
$total=$_POST['total'];
$dateAdvance = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dateAdvance']));
```

Comment: This is what i wrote in the code for the datapicker: $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });

Comment: OK, so it is jquery-ui datepicker and the format is DD-MM-YY. If You use the code above in my answer You should be able to store it into the DB `date` type column.

Comment: It did not help, it is still not saving the date, I am getting 0000-00-00 out in the database

Comment: If You do a `var_dump($_POST['dateAdvance']);` what does it print out?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateAdvance=$_POST['total'];
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dateAdvance']));


in mysql_query in place of $dateAdvance write $date
```

Comment: if you don't have reason to tell then dont give downvote simply

Comment: I can se you have a "t" at the end of your dateAdvancet but I don't, so I can't se where I hav a different. Please tell me if there is something else I don't see.

Comment: 'dateAdvancet' date NOT NULL, read this line what you have posted

Comment: Thankyou you are right, but sadly it dit not solve the problem

Comment: can you share your full php page code..Any error you are getting?